# Using Slick with shapeless HList

Tags: scala, slick, shapeless, hlist

*Slick's* support for `HList` is generally a great thing. Unfortunately, it comes with its own implementation that does barely provide any useful operations. I'd therefore like to use the *shapeless* `HList` instead. This is supposed to be "[trivial](https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/208#issuecomment-24686666)", but I have no idea how to get this right. Searching the web I found no evidence that somebody managed to accomplish this task.

I assume that it's enough to implement a `ProvenShape` (as advertised [here](https://twitter.com/stefanzeiger/status/361606509932707845)), but since I fail to understand the concept of *Slick's* `(Proven)Shape`s, I did not manage implement this.

I'm basically aiming to boil this

```
class   Users( tag: Tag )
extends Table[Long :: String :: HNil]( tag, "users" )
{
    def id = column[Long]( "id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )

    def email = column[String]( "email" )

    override def * = ( id, email ) <>[TableElementType, ( Long, String )](
        _.productElements,
        hlist => Some( hlist.tupled )
    )
}
```

down to

```
class   Users( tag: Tag )
extends Table[Long :: String :: HNil]( tag, "users" )
{
    def id = column[Long]( "id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc )

    def email = column[String]( "email" )

    override def * = id :: email :: HNil
}
```

Comment: not an answer, but this thread looks relevant: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/519

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You hit the nail on the head - if you can produce `Shapes` for `HLists`, the rest of Slick's machinery will kick into gear to produce the `ProvenShape` you need for the default projection.

Here's a bare-bones implementation that allows you to create `Tables` of `HLists`:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import shapeless.{ HList, ::, HNil }
import slick.lifted.{ Shape, ShapeLevel, MappedProductShape }

final class HListShape[L <: ShapeLevel, M <: HList, U <: HList : ClassTag, P <: HList]
    (val shapes: Seq[Shape[_, _, _, _]]) extends MappedProductShape[L, HList, M, U, P] {

  def buildValue(elems: IndexedSeq[Any]) =
    elems.foldRight(HNil: HList)(_ :: _)

  def copy(shapes: Seq[Shape[_ <: ShapeLevel, _, _, _]]) =
    new HListShape(shapes)

  def classTag: ClassTag[U] = implicitly

  def runtimeList(value: HList): List[Any] = {
    @tailrec def loop(value: HList, acc: List[Any] = Nil): List[Any] = value match {
      case HNil     => acc
      case hd :: tl => loop(tl, hd :: acc)
    }

    loop(value).reverse
  }

  override def getIterator(value: HList): Iterator[Any] =
    runtimeList(value).iterator

  def getElement(value: HList, idx: Int): Any =
    runtimeList(value)(idx)
}

object HListShape {
  implicit def hnilShape[L <: ShapeLevel]: HListShape[L, HNil, HNil, HNil] =
    new HListShape[L, HNil, HNil, HNil](Nil)

  implicit def hconsShape[L <: ShapeLevel, M1, M2 <: HList, U1, U2 <: HList, P1, P2 <: HList]
      (implicit s1: Shape[_ <: ShapeLevel, M1, U1, P1], s2: HListShape[_ <: ShapeLevel, M2, U2, P2]):
      HListShape[L, M1 :: M2, U1 :: U2, P1 :: P2] =
    new HListShape[L, M1 :: M2, U1 :: U2, P1 :: P2](s1 +: s2.shapes)
}
```

I've put an implementation on Github [here](https://github.com/underscoreio/slickless). In principle I think `Generic` could be brought into the fray to map case classes without the need for `<>`.

Comment: You should have called the repo "shapefull" ;)

Comment: Ack! What a missed opportunity. Seems so obvious in hind-sight :)